# After solving git rebase merge conflict another branch is created. How to solve this situation?

Tags: git, rebase

I created a file a.txt.

- I am on master branch Then I added text "m1" and made a commit with message "m1".
- Then appended "m2" to the same file and committed with message "m2".
- Then I created and checked out a new branch "feature".
- There I appended text "f1" and committed with message "f1".
- Then I checkout to master and added text "m3".

> So in master branch now the a.txt file has the texts "m1 m2 m3"

> in feature branch the a.txt file has the texts "m1 m2 f1"

- Then I checked out to feature branch again
- Now as I am in feature branch, I typed `git rebase master` and I got merge conflict as usual.
- Then I resolved the conflict in the file and run `git add a.txt` and `git rebase --continue` it instantly showed me to type a new commit message and I typed a commit message.
- Now I typed `git branch` and found like below

```
* (no branch, rebasing feature)
feature
master
```

Then I again ran `git rebase --continue` it is showed me

```
a.txt: needs merge
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

**Edit:** I found some more conflicts again. I had to solve those and then run `git add` and `git rebase --continue`. This was a very long run. Can anybody explain why I had to solve conflicts two times?

My goal is to rebase master from feature branch. And finally rebasing feature branch from master branch.

Comment: Are you still rebasing? If that's the case, then it's all fine. The branch where you were working when you started the rebase will be moved when you are done.

Comment: @eftshift0 How should I continue to reabase. After "git rebase --continue" it didn't showed me any error other than typing a commit message.

Comment: I again tried to type the same command "git rebase --continue" now and it is now showing me 
git rebase --continue
------------------------
a.txt: needs merge
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
--------------------
and now I have found more conflicts in the same file

Comment: You run `git rebase --continue` and it should continue until it finds more conflicts... or there are instructions to stop (like you asked to edit on a revision) or it finishes and then you know it's done.

Comment: Oh... ok.... so you asked to continue _but_ you still haven't added. What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: @eftshift0 as per your suggestion it showed me again one step more conflicts. I solved the conflicts and run "git add" and "git rebase --continue". Now the temporary branch is removed and I automatically checked out to feature branch. Could you please explain me why I had to solve conflicts two times and two times rebase ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233938/discussion-between-kayesh-parvez-and-eftshift0).

Comment: You mean, while doing a rebase? Sure, rebase applies revisions _one at a time_, and many of those revisions could generate conflicts... even on the same files. If you were doing a merge instead, you would only have to solve conflicts once. There might be situations where merging would not produce conflicts but if you tried rebasing instead you would see conflicts.

Comment: Sorry but merge conflicts at different steps of a rebase are not surprising so what's the actual question here? Also unclear what "My goal is to rebase master from feature branch. And finally rebasing feature branch from master branch" actually means.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the entire sequence of steps mentioned by you without any intermediate branches being created, and the rebase worked as expected on the feature branch as well as master. There are a couple of things mentioned below that you can perhaps double check to ensure clean rebasing.

1. As soon as the conflict occurs execute `git reset .` (as recommended by git), before starting to edit `a.txt`. Finally execute `git add .` or `git add a.txt`.
2. While resolving conflicts, ensure to remove all the git conflict marker characters `(<<< === >>>)` as shown below:

**Before**

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
m1 m2 m3
=======
m1 m2 f1
>>>>>>> f1
```

**After**

```
m1 m2 m3 f1
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do what you say you're doing, what you describe doesn't happen.

```
testit () {
( set -x;
git init `mktemp -d`; cd $_
echo m1 >file.txt; git add .; git commit -mm1
echo m2 >>file.txt; git commit -amm2
git checkout -b feature
echo f1 >>file.txt; git commit -amf1
git checkout master
echo m3 >>file.txt; git commit -amm3
git rebase master feature
vi file.txt
git add .
git rebase --continue
)
}
```

and the continue produces a successful rebase.